# Why do we need multiple "await" keywords if "await" stops execution of the asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Per [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/async-await), `await` "suspends the function execution until the promise settles, and then resumes it with the promise result." If this is the case, why do we sometimes need multiple `await` keywords within one function?

Consider the following example:

```
async function fetchdata() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)
}
fetchdata()
```

This returns an array of objects retrieved from the given URL. But if `await` really suspends execution of `fetchdata`, I would expect to get the same return value if I removed the second `await` keyword, since the resulting `const data = response.json()` should still only run once `response` is settled.

However, when I run the below code, `fetchdata()` returns a pending Promise, i.e. it appears `response.json()` was run before `response` was actually settled.

```
async function fetchdata() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
  const data = response.json()
  console.log(data)
}
fetchdata()
```

Can someone explain to me what I am misunderstanding about the `await` keyword?

Comment: Important point: the `fetch()` API calls resolves the initial Promise when the HTTP response first *starts* to be received. You have to `await` the `.json()` method because it cannot finish until the last bytes of the response have made it to the caller.

Comment: In other words, `response.json()` is *not* the same as ordinary `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need multiple `await` statements because you have multiple promises.

The `json()` method returns a promise (which resolves when the entire request body has been read and parsed).

This is because the promise returned by `fetch()` resolves when the header list is available. This lets you make decisions about what to do next without waiting for the entire body to be transferred across the network.

It also lets you process the body as a stream using the [`body` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body) so you can handle a very large response piece by piece by piece as it comes in instead of storing the whole, raw response in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `json()` function itself needs awaiting because it returns a Promise